# How to use Hibernate SQL projection query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a SQL projection query that returns a list, but I want a single result. Here is my projection query:

```java
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TbLoyaltytrans.class)
  .add(Restrictions.eq("custid", custId))
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
  .add(Projections.sum("pointin").as("pointin"))
  .add(Projections.sum("pointout").as("pointout"))
  .add(Projections.sqlProjection(
        "(pointin - pointout) as points",  
        new String[]{"points"}, 
        new org.hibernate.type.DoubleType[]{
              new org.hibernate.type.DoubleType()
        }),
        "points")
  );
```

I want a single object, i.e.: the `count` from the above query.

What I did wrong with the above query?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your are using `criteria.list()` in order to get the list. You can use `criteria.uniqueResult()` and it will return a single Object or null.

Comment: i got the ans i just return `(Object[]) criteria.uniqueResult()` and iterate this as i understand by using projection you will get three results as output in above query 1st if for `Projections.sum("pointin").as("pointin")` sencond is for `Projections.sum("pointout").as("pointout"))` and the last one is your SQLprojection output that i want i iterate this array and fetch third position like `Double reedeemPoints =new Double(obj[2].toString())` and it works for me thank you for your ans

Comment: If it really worked to you, your could accept his answer. Thanks!